# Server Socket hangs in Close_Wait

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

The scenario is the following:
I am sending bulk of data to clients from my C# Server Application.
All of a sudden Data flow stopped, No data Update in Client Side and the port gets blocked.

When this occurs, the Server side symptoms are

1. Close_Wait in that port (netstat)
2. Operation Would block (Error code : 135) in Log.
3. Unable to make a new Connection from client.
4. Telnet Fails to that Port

Currently we restart the server whenever the issue arise. Obviously this is not a solution.

Can someone offer a solution for Server socket stuck in Close_Wait in windows server 2008?
Any suggestion for this scenario would be appreciated gratefully.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLOSE_WAIT means the peer has closed the connection and TCP is waiting for the local application to close the socket.

So close it.

Comment: Im using IPWorks here no way to send Shutdown, only close(). I think close internally contains shutdown(). No problem while using my Asynchronous Socket (winsock) instead of ipworks . But in IPWorks , i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: @MSK Shutdown has precisely nothing to do with my answer. Situation remains the same. Close the socket.